# Bad CLS results on single pages even with FlyingPress and good WordPress settings

Tags: wordpress, caching, core-web-vitals

[image: Screenshot of Google PageSpeed Insights' analysis results]

Hello, I am using WordPress, FlyingPress and other plugins to manage speed on my site.

Unfortunately on single post pages I still have a bad CLS result that makes my test not pass as a good URL on Google Pagespeed.

Could you help me?

https://pagespeed.web.dev/report?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.rnbjunk.com%2Ftraduzione-testo-another-love-tom-odell-876%2F

Answer (score 0):

CLS is there even without [FlyingPress](https://flying-press.com) (You can check it here: https://pagespeed.web.dev/report?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.rnbjunk.com%2Ftraduzione-testo-another-love-tom-odell-876%2F%3Fno_optimize&use_original_url=true)

Your ads don't have a fixed width/height or aspect ratio. It's creating CLS a lot. Add width/height or aspect ratio to the ads.